# SAS check if column exist in Table

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I want to make a macro That check if all the columns in col_to_check are in Table and I want exit SAS if one of these columns doesn't exit

I try this:

%let col_to_check = ID SEG AGE;

%MACRO check(table , col_to_check);

```
%local count;
%let count=0;

%DO i_=1 %TO %sysfunc(countw(&col_to_check.," "));  

        %LET col=%SCAN(&col_to_check.,&i_.," ");
        %if ( %varexist(&table.,&col.) = 1) %then endsas;
%END;
```

%MEND check;

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53622451/return-true-value-if-column-exists-in-sas-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `vcolumn` table of the `sashelp` library.

```
%macro check(lib, table, col_to_check);
    %let nb_col = %sysfunc(countw(&col_to_check., %quote( )));
    %let col_names = "%sysfunc(tranwrd(&col_to_check.,%str( )," "))";

    proc sql noprint;
        select count(distinct name) into :nb 
        from sashelp.vcolumn where upcase(name) in (&col_names.) 
           and upcase(libname)="&lib." 
           and upcase(memname)="&table.";
    quit;

    %if &nb. ^=&nb_col. %then
        %goto end_pg;
    %else
        %do;
            %put do stuff;
        %end;
%end_pg:
%mend;

%check(SASHELP, CLASS, SEX WEIGHT NAME AGE);
```

PS: What do you mean by "exit SAS"? You could easily replace the `%goto` by [%ABORT](http://support.sas.com/kb/23/addl/fusion23211_1_abort.html)

Comment: exit it's for stop the program

Comment: what should be lib if my table is in the WORK, I try lib = WORK but this does'nt work

Comment: lib should be WORK. Please provide the error that you get. Make sure the table is created in WORK before running the macro.